# Android UPI Payment without any payment gateway

Tags: android, upi

Is there any way to directly implement UPI payment in android to a merchant ID/VPA without using a payment gateway like Razorpay / PayU etc?

I have tried using Upi deeplink approach (upi://pay?pa=xxx@xxxx&pn=xxxxxx&mc=null&tid=null&tr=test101&tn=This%20is%20test%20payment&am=10&mam=null&cu=INR&url=null) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
        val request = "upi://pay?pa=merchantVPA&pn=merchantName&mc=merchantcode&tr=transactionID&am=amount&cu=INR"
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.data = Uri.parse(request)

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

Comment: Using this deeplink with correct values I get "Your payment failed as the payment mode is not allowed for this UPI ID"

Comment: The receiver upi id should be a merchant upi id not an individual id.

Comment: After adding merchant upi id I get this error - "You have exceeded the bank limit for this payment. Retry with a smaller amount". Amount is only Rs 1

This is the actual deeplink - upi://pay?pa=boostplus@hdfcbank&pn=CPR&tr=12347876766565&am=1&cu=INR

Comment: Try to generate a unique transaction code (tr) for each transaction before you initiate payment process.

Comment: Also check you might exceeded daily upi transaction limit (10 transactions per day).

Comment: What will be the min amount per transaction ?